# How do I target and change all my h2 tags in my HTML document with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, tags, addeventlistener

I have a HTML document with different headings in either h1 or h2. The h2 headings have a class of 'subHeadline'. I want to make all the h2 tags turn white when I click them.

In my JavaScript code below you can see that I´ve tried to target all the elements in the HTML document with a class of 'subHeadline'. However, it only makes the first h2 tag turn white when I click it. How do I make all of the h2 headlines turn white if clicked? Here´s my code:

```
<h1> The first h1</h1>
<p> Random paragraph text. </p>

<h1> The second h1</h1>
<p> Random paragraph text. </p>

<h1> The third h1</h1>
<p> Random paragraph text. </p>

<h2 class="subHeadline"> The first h2</h2>
<p> Random paragraph text. </p>

<h2 class="subHeadline"> The second h2</h2>
<p> Random paragraph text. </p>

<h2 class="subHeadline"> The third h2</h2>
<p> Random paragraph text. </p>
<script>

let headline = document.querySelector('h1');
headline.addEventListener('click', changeHeader);

function changeHeader() {
  headline.style.color = 'white';
}

let subHead = document.querySelector('.subHeadline');
subHead.addEventListener('click', changeSubheader);

function changeSubheader() {
  subHead.style.color = 'white';
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to iterate over all of your headers and attach the event handlers.

For this, you can use `querySelectorAll` and `forEach`. See the doc for [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

As suggested by @Andreas below, you can use a single `querySelectorAll` for both headers and subHeadlines:

```
document.querySelectorAll('h1, .subHeadline');
```

You will need to do a small change to your function to take the click event as argument. This event as a `target` property which will be the header you've clicked.

```js
function changeColor(event) {
  event.target.style.color = 'white';
}

document.querySelectorAll('h1, .subHeadline')
  .forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', changeColor));
```

```html
<h1> The first h1</h1>
<p> Random paragraph text. </p>

<h1> The second h1</h1>
<p> Random paragraph text. </p>

<h1> The third h1</h1>
<p> Random paragraph text. </p>

<h2 class="subHeadline"> The first h2</h2>
<p> Random paragraph text. </p>

<h2 class="subHeadline"> The second h2</h2>
<p> Random paragraph text. </p>

<h2 class="subHeadline"> The third h2</h2>
<p> Random paragraph text. </p>
```

Comment: You can do this with one `.querySelectorCall()` call: `.querySelectorAll("h1, .subHeadline")`

Answer (score 1):

`document.querySelector` only finds the *first* matching element in the document - which is why your event listeners were only working on the first elements. To fix it, use `querySelectorAll` instead, and iterate through the resulting collection to add the listeners individually.

Note that I've had to change your event listeners so they only affect the element clicked on. They take the event object itself as an argument (which here I've called `e`, which is a common convention), and then `e.target` is the actual element clicked on.

```js
let headlines = document.querySelectorAll('h1');
headlines.forEach(headline => headline.addEventListener('click', changeHeader));

function changeHeader(e) {
  e.target.style.color = 'white';
}

let subHeaders = document.querySelectorAll('.subHeadline');
subHeaders.forEach(subhead => subhead.addEventListener('click', changeSubheader));

function changeSubheader(e) {
  e.target.style.color = 'white';
}
```

```html
<h1> The first h1</h1>
<p> Random paragraph text. </p>

<h1> The second h1</h1>
<p> Random paragraph text. </p>

<h1> The third h1</h1>
<p> Random paragraph text. </p>

<h2 class="subHeadline"> The first h2</h2>
<p> Random paragraph text. </p>

<h2 class="subHeadline"> The second h2</h2>
<p> Random paragraph text. </p>

<h2 class="subHeadline"> The third h2</h2>
<p> Random paragraph text. </p>
```

Answer (score 1):

use onclick event on the tags and pass the element itself tot he function and turn them white

```js
function a(e) {
  e.style.color = 'white';
}
```

```html
<h1> The first h1</h1>
<p> Random paragraph text. </p>

<h1> The second h1</h1>
<p> Random paragraph text. </p>

<h1> The third h1</h1>
<p> Random paragraph text. </p>

<h2 class="subHeadline" onclick="a(this)"> The first h2</h2>
<p> Random paragraph text. </p>

<h2 class="subHeadline"  onclick="a(this)"> The second h2</h2>
<p> Random paragraph text. </p>

<h2 class="subHeadline" onclick="a(this)"> The third h2</h2>
<p> Random paragraph text. </p>
```